# Search file duplicates in OSX by hash

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, spotlight, search, file

I am looking for a way to search for a determinate file in OSX (Maverick but more generally OSX).
In particular I would like to do the following:
given a File_001 I'd like to search if in the filesystem exists a copy of this file.
Not just with the same name, I would like the comparison method to be an hashing algorithm like MD5, SHA etc..

Most of the "duplicate file finder" I have tried just search for all the duplicates in a drive/system. I would, instead, be interested in submitting one file and search for its duplicates.

Does anyone know if such a program exists? Maybe some obscure function of Spotlight?

Comment: Be wary of a hash determining whether a given file is a copy. This approach may fail with .emlx files (Apple Mail's file format), for example. As an aid to Spotlight, OSX appends metadata to mail files. The same email in two different paths may have different metadata even though the Message-id is the same. Different hash for two files containing the exact same raw email.

Answer (score 22):

You might also use `fdupes`. It doesn't have an option to search for duplicates of a specific file, but you can just grep the output for the filename:

```
fdupes -r1 .|grep filename
```

`-r` recurses into directories and `-1` prints each group of duplicate files on a single line.

Other useful examples:

`fdupes -r .`  finds all duplicate files under the current directory;

`fdupes -r . -dN`  deletes all except the first duplicate from each group of duplicates;

`fdupes -r dir1 dir2|grep dir1/|xargs rm` removes duplicates in `dir1`.

You can install `fdupes` with `brew install fdupes`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a list of files that are NOT a duplicate in the current directory?

Answer (score 7):

You can easily build this yourself with some shell commands:

- `find ~ -type f -exec md5 -r '{}' \; > /tmp/md5.list`

  will build a list of md5 hashes over all your files.
- `grep $(md5 -q FILE-TO-SEARCH) /tmp/md5.list`

  will search for the md5 hash of FILE-TO-SEARCH

Running the first command (especially if you run it across the whole disc) will take a long time though.

---

If you only want to search for one file, you can also use

```
SIZE=$(stat -f '%z' FILE-TO-SEARCH)
MD5=$(md5 -q FILE-TO-SEARCH)
find ~ -type f -size ${SIZE}c | while read f; do
    [[ $MD5 = $(md5 -q "$f") ]] && echo $f
done
```

Comment: The very first pass should be a find by exact size operation.

Comment: @biziclop If you only want to search for one file, yes. If you want to search for several it's faster to build the index once and just search through the index file afterwards.

Comment: It's true of course, I just noticed this sentence in the question: "I would, instead, be interested in submitting one file and search for its duplicates."

Comment: fdupes should be faster has it first do date comparison, then partial hash, then full hash.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you substitute the size and hash for FILE_001 into the command.

198452 bytes is the file size I used and the file md5 hash is 3915dc84b4f464d0d550113287c8273b

```
find . -type f -size 198452c -exec md5 -r {} \; |
    grep -o "3915dc84b4f464d0d550113287c8273b\ \(.*\)" | awk '{print $2}'
```

The output will be a list of files with path names relative to the directory sent to the find command.

This approach has the advantage that it will only hash files that match the size of your original and will only output file names that match the hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with scripts, you can get close to the behavior you want with [Araxis Find Duplicate Files](http://www.araxis.com/find-duplicate-files/) $10 in the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/araxis-find-duplicate-files/id438438956?ls=1&mt=12). There is also a 7 day demo on their web site. Find Duplicate Files searches for dupes by computing the hash for each file.

You can approximate the behavior you want you would set up a folder with the single file you are concerned about, then add the folders you want to search in. This will also report other dupes, if there are any, in the search paths.

This app has many nice sorting features making the results very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting some changes to [Lri's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118566/search-file-duplicates-in-osx-by-hash/118752#118752). `xargs` runs into issues when path names have special characters. Since `fdupes` doesn't have a `-print0` flag to pass to `xargs` like `find` does - it trips up.

The following command results in an error because of a single quote in a filename:

`fdupes -r dir1 dir2|grep dir1/|xargs rm`

> xargs: unterminated quote

The UNIX way around this is to add another command between the `grep` and `xarg` commands and adding additional flags to `xargs`:

`... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 ...`

This addition comes from an excellent explanation at [Make xargs execute the command once for each line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28806991/2031849)

The full command would then be:

`fdupes -r dir1 dir2 |grep "dir2/" |tr '\n' '\0' |xargs -0 -n1 rm -v`

Adding the `-v` flag allows you to see what has been removed.

**Check this command first using `echo` or another non-destructive command before using `rm`.**

An example of a non-destructive option is to use the `tag` command *(install with homebrew)*. Add a red Finder tag to files that are duplicates so you can manually select and drag to trash :)

```
fdupes -r dir1 dir2 | grep  "dir2" |  tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 -I % tag -a red %
```