# Is there a Byte-By-Byte Duplicate File Removal app for Mac? (not SHA-1 or MD5 hash!)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file

I recently switched to Mac and spent way too many hours on PC trying every duplicate removal app, eventually discovering that **byte-by-byte checking** was necessary to get accurate (***safe***) results, and finally then settling on AllDup as the best app for this purpose.

Mac options seem more limited and I have not found any that do byte-by-byte checking, they don't even necessarily state on their website what algorithm(s) they use! Any tips? Must also work on Yosemite.

Comment: SHA-1 guarantees uniqueness of file data with an extremely high probability. Comparing files byte by byte would be very inefficient and pointless.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you find files with the same SHA-1 or [MD5 hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756004/can-two-different-strings-generate-the-same-md5-hash-code) but different content on your computer. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118566/search-file-duplicates-in-osx-by-hash?rq=1 for some options to find dupes based on hashes.

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to specify as many requirements as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do worse than to try **dupeGuru**, available from [Hardcoded Software](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/), I've had very good results with it. It presents numerous options for fine-tuning your search and will perform byte-checking comparisons.

In addition to the standard dupeGuru there is a [music edition](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_me/) as well as a [picture edition](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/) for more specific media searches. It's free so give it a go with some test files and see what mileage you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try to instal this one https://www.cleverfiles.com/duplicate-file-finder-remover.html
It's a good freeware alternative to some paid programs. 
This app scans your Mac for all kinds of duplicates and does this really fast. It also features flexible auto-selection rules, so you won't need to scoop through the duplicates manually.

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't specify whether the app actually performs byte-by-byte comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think the duplicate finder [Gemini 2](http://macpaw.7eer.net/c/402409/66209/1733?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmacpaw.com%2Fgemini) is such an app you are finding, it can find duplicate files by contents(byte-by-byte checking) and file name, it even can sort out the similar photos in your photo library. Works quite well for me so far, you are going to give it a try.